# What is the fastest way to pull massive amounts of data from Snowflake Database into AWS SageMaker?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sagemaker

What would be the fastest way to pull in very large datasets from Snowflake into my SageMaker instance in AWS? How does the snowflake python connector (what I currently use) compare to lets say a spark connector to snowflake?

Comment: Why do you want to pull large datasets? (vs pushing computation down to Snowflake via Snowpark or SQL)

Comment: I'd like to pull datasets down into SageMaker to do some ml based forecasting. Is Snowpark even ready for public use?

Comment: Correct on Snowpark - some features are in private preview and could help every user soon. But still, when asking for "fastest" it's good to add more specifics, like the intended usage (ML based forecasting) and what you mean by "massive amounts" - so others can provide better help.

Comment: I mean around a billion rows and about 10 fields. Is there an alternative to snowpark as it's not fully out? Also, what are your thoughts on the snowflake python connector vs spark?

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker training jobs like S3 as the input source, but you can also use EFS (NFS) or FSx for Lustre, for higher performance

For S3, I'd use AWS Glue [to read from Snowflake](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/ingest-data-from-snowflake-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-glue-marketplace-connectors/) or use Spark on EMR, and store the data in partitions in S3. Partitioning would allow you to distribute your training across multiple machines, if your algorithm supports it

There's also [`copy into`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html) in Snowflake

Ideally, you'd store in Parquet format, but [gzipped] CSV is the common format for SageMaker built-in algorithms. If you're using your own algorithm, then probably go with Parquet

If you're doing forecasting, you could also use [Amazon Forecast](https://aws.amazon.com/forecast/), but it can get pricey